# R - Compute increments for use in power variation

Tags: r, sum, binomial-coefficients

I am working with high frequent data, which is a vector X of decimal numbers.

I would like to code the following in R, but am at complete loss where to start: 
[image]

**n** decides how big intervals we are looking at. This can be any value, this is not so important, since I need to experiment with different values.

I have tried a lot of things, amongst the following:

```
X <- runif(10000) # 5000 obs. pr. second, with 20 mill obs in total

for(i in 1:length(X){
sum? * (-1)^??
*(for (n in 0:i) print(choose(n, k = 0:n)))
x <- ??
mat[1:length(X)] <- x
}
```

But I am miles from anything working. Any help is greatly appreciated. I've edited the equation, missed an equal sign.

I've written something that hopefully should make it more clear:
[image]

Comment: I am unclear on what the delta with n and i,k means, could you clarify? I'm also not sure what X_{(i-j)/n} is: couldn't that value be a non-integer and therefore not make sense as an index of X?

Comment: I think it is not well defined since that term X_(i-j)/n results in fractional subscripts, as David Robinson pointed out actually.... (just noticed). Looks cool though :)

Comment: Can you give a link to the original definition? Or a screen shot? I think there is an error in the displayed equation. I actually think the final /n belongs outside the summation, or at least it is not in the subscript

Comment: The result is going to be a three dimensional matrix (in this sense: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63074/is-there-a-3-dimensional-matrix-by-matrix-product , there are other ways to use the term "three dimensional matrix"). That will make display and visualization of the results rather difficult.

Comment: Tried to write something more about it, any help very much appreciated! :D

Comment: I see now. I have never seen the subscript used like that, it is more like a function argument, but of course it is perfectly valid.

Comment: I would think you would have to have a smoother function than runif(0,1) for this to be meaningful.

Comment: Have you had a look at the solution I submitted?

Comment: Yup, looking at it now, very nice! I'll follow up once I get it working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can get you started. I think it is what you expressed. However I think it would make more sense with an initialization like rnorm(nx,1,0.01) - i.e. something smoother. It might also make sense to have xsub interpolate between the generated points (i.e. make it a continuous function).

It could obviously be made more efficient but it should be verified to be correct first.

Also I really don't know how to interpret the results or I would have done a plot.

```
nx <- 100
secs <- 2
x <- runif(nx)
obspersec <- nx/secs

xsub <- function(t){
   i <- trunc(t*obspersec)+1
   if (i<=0) return(0)
   if (i>nx) return(0)
   return(x[i])
}

x_njk <- function (n,i,k){
  if (i<k){
    return (0)
  } 
  sum <- 0
  for (j in 0:k){
    term <- ((-1)^j)*choose(k,j)*xsub((i-j)/n)
    sum <- sum + term 
  }
  return(sum)
}

n <- 100

for (k in 1:2){
   for (i in k:10){
     print(sprintf("n:%d i:%d k:%d  x_njk:%.5f",n,i,k,x_njk(n,i,k)))
   }
}
```

Comment: This is really great. Just to be sure, nx is the number of observations in x or just the length of x. secs is the number of seconds. I am having difficulty understanding what xsub does?

Comment: Also, in the last function is it correct that k goes from 1 up to the number of seconds? But what about i? Why does this go to 10?

Comment: xsub just calculates the X_(i-j)/n term. I guard it to be zero outside of its domain of definition, but one could clamp it to the endpoints instead. I kind of think it should be made continuous, the way it is implemented here it is a step function with the number of steps being n.

Comment: The values that k and i range over were chosen arbitrarily here, i just wanted to test it and make sure it worked over a decent range of definition.

Comment: It could be that xsub needs a more elaborate definition based on that integral, but I assumed from your code you just wanted it to be some random normalized uniform noise.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've done it manually, and your solution works great. I can understand your concern about xsub, but I think it is okay. My data is 5000 obs. per second. I'll have a go at 4.28 now based on your help, thanks!